# Jekyll - sort pages by integer

Tags: sorting, jekyll

I have some problem of pages with a custom attribute 'n', taking integer values. I would like to iterate through them in order. However,

```
{% assign pp = site.pages | sort:"n"  %}
{% for p in pp %}

...

{% endfor %}
```

only sorts the attribute values as strings, so I obtain

1, 10, 2, 3, ...

How do I sort by numerical value? I need a plugin-free solution since I am using github.

Comment: FYI.. it's not merged yet, but there is an open pull request for Liquid to provide `sort_numeric`: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/1028

Answer (score 0):

If your `page.n` are sorted like strings, maybe you assign them like string (`n: "1"`).

Be sure to assign them like integers (`n: 1`).

Comment: I did assign them as integers as you suggested, but the same issue remains.

Comment: Control with {{ page.n | inspect }} did it return `1` or `"1"` ?

Comment: It looks like all jekyll frontmatter comes through as strings. I have `n: 1` in my frontmatter, and inspecting it returns `n="1"`. So I guess the question is how to cast strings to ints prior to sorting.

Comment: It seems that strings are cast to integers via adding 0: `{{assign i = n | plus: 0}}`. However, this isn't a complete solution because I don't know how to sort based on assigned variables.

Comment: I thought I would be clever by inputing all the integers using hexadecimal. By prepending `0x` before the number, it forces jekyll to parse them as integers (verified with `inspect`). However, sort still casts them to strings! So far my best workaround is to make all the variables quoted numbers of the same length (e.g. `n: "00010"`). They have to be quoted or they get interpretted as octal integers.